# how to expose the property from python to QMLin tree view

Tags: python, qml, treeview, pyside2

i have a requirement where i have to expose certain properties written in python to the QML side of tree view I am unable to do so as i am not very sure of how to do it.

This is the Code that i have written for my treeview back end in order for me to parse the JSON model inside my treeviewModel class

tree_Model.py

```
import PySide2
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractItemModel, QByteArray
from PySide2.QtGui import Qt
from TreeItem import TreeItem


class tree_Model(QAbstractItemModel):
    SchoolNameRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    FirstNameRole = Qt.UserRole + 2
    LastNameRole = Qt.UserRole + 3
    GenderRole = Qt.UserRole + 4
    AgeRole = Qt.UserRole + 5
    PhoneNumberRole = Qt.UserRole + 6

def __init__(self , data , parent = None):
    super(tree_Model, self).__init__(parent)
    print("wohoo came off pa")
    self.rootItem = TreeItem({"SchoolName","FirstName","LastName","Gender","Age","PhoneNumber"})
    self.setupModelData(data,self.rootItem)


def roleNames(self):
    roles = {
        tree_Model.SchoolNameRole: QByteArray(b'SchoolName'),
        tree_Model.FirstNameRole: QByteArray(b'FirstName'),
        tree_Model.LastNameRole: QByteArray(b'LastName'),
        tree_Model.GenderRole: QByteArray(b'Gender'),
        tree_Model.AgeRole: QByteArray(b'Age'),
        tree_Model.PhoneNumberRole: QByteArray(b'PhoneNumber')
        }
    return roles

def columnCount(self, parent: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) -> int:
    if parent.isValid():
        return parent.internalPointer().columnCount()
    else:
        return self.rootItem.columnCount()

def data(self, index: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex, role: int):
    if not index.isValid():
        return None
    item: TreeItem = index.internalPointer()
    if role == tree_Model.SchoolNameRole:
        if item.isSchool_QProperty:
            return item

    if role == tree_Model.FirstNameRole:
        if not item.isSchool_QProperty:
            return item.StudentData['Firstname']

    if role == tree_Model.LastNameRole:

        if not item.isSchool_QProperty:
            return item.StudentData['LastName']

    if role == tree_Model.GenderRole:
        if not item.isSchool_QProperty:
            return item.StudentData['Gender']

    if role == tree_Model.AgeRole:
        if not item.isSchool_QProperty:
            return item.StudentData['Age']

    if role == tree_Model.PhoneNumberRole:
        if not item.isSchool_QProperty:
            return item.StudentData['PhoneNumber']

    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        return item.value

    if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return None

    return item.StudentData

def flags(self, index: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) -> PySide2.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags:

    if not index.isValid():
        return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

    if index.internalPointer().isStudent:
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
    else:
        return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Orientation, role: int):
    if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return self.rootItem.data(section)
    return None

def index(self, row: int, column: int,
          parent: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) -> PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex:

    if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    if not parent.isValid():
        parentItem = self.rootItem
    else:
        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()  # type: ignore[assignment] #[BLRFPGT-869]

    childItem = parentItem.child(row)
    if childItem:
        return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
    else:
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()
def parent(self, index: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) -> PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex:

    if not index.isValid():
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    childItem = index.internalPointer()
    parentItem: TreeItem = childItem.parent()

    if parentItem == self.rootItem:
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()
    return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)

def rowCount(self, parent: PySide2.QtCore.QModelIndex) -> int:

    if parent.column() > 0:
        return 0

    if not parent.isValid():
        parentItem = self.rootItem
    else:
        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

    return parentItem.childCount()

def setupModelData(self,jsondata, parent: TreeItem) -> None:
    parents = [parent]
    number = 0

    while number < len(jsondata):
        position = 0
        while position < len(jsondata[number]):
            if jsondata[number][position] != ' ':
                break
            position += 1

        json_value = jsondata[number][position:]
        if json_value:
            schoolItem = TreeItem(json_value[0], parents[-1])
            schoolItem.isSchool_QProperty = True
            schoolItem.isStudent_QProperty = False
            schoolItem.schoolName_QProperty = json_value[0]
            for students in json_value[1]:
                studentItem = TreeItem(students, schoolItem)
                schoolItem.appendChild(studentItem)
                studentItem.isStudent_QProperty = True
                studentItem.isSchool_QProperty = False
            parents[-1].appendChild(schoolItem)
        number += 1
```

TreeItem.py

```
class TreeItem(QObject):
    def __init__(self, data, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.StudentData = data
        self.childItems = []
        self._schoolName = None
        self._isSchool = False
        self._isStudent = False
    def appendChild(self, item) ->None:
        self.childItems.append(item)

    def child(self, row:int):
        return self.childItems[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childItems)

    def columnCount(self):
        return len(self.StudentData)

    def data(self, column: int):
        try:
            data = self.StudentData[column]
            return data
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentItem

    def row(self) -> int:
        if self.parentItem:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)
        return 0

    def schoolName(self) -> str:
        return self._schoolName

    def schoolName_set(self, schoolName: str):
        self._schoolName = schoolName

    schoolName_QProperty = Property(str, schoolName, schoolName_set)

    def isSchool(self) -> bool:
        return self._isSchool

    def isSchool_set(self, isSchool: bool) -> None:
        self._isSchool = isSchool

    isSchool_QProperty = Property(bool, isSchool, isSchool_set)

    def isStudent(self) -> bool:
        return self._isStudent

    def isStudent_set(self, isStudent: bool) -> None:
            self._isStudent = isStudent

    isStudent_QProperty = Property(bool, isStudent, isStudent_set)
```

i have exposed everyitem to qml by making them QProperty.

main.py

```
import json
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication,Qt
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from tree_Model import tree_Model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    school_Student_Model = []
    with open("sample4.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for i in data['SchoolList']:
            print("the school names are", i['SchoolName'])
            school_name = i['SchoolName']
            students_info = i["Students"]
            school_Student_Model.append((school_name, students_info))
    model = tree_Model(school_Student_Model)
    model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("schoolModel", model)
    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in QML how to i access these QProperty  this is what i have tried and it doesnt seem to work

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    TreeView{
        id: schoolTreeView
        model: schoolModel
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        alternatingRowColors: true
        TableViewColumn{
            id:schoolName_id
            title: "SchoolName"
            role: "SchoolName"
            width: 100
            delegate: someDelegate

        }

        Component{
            id:someDelegate
            Item {
                id: schoolname_id
                Label{
                    text: styleData.value.schoolName_QProperty
                }
            }
        }
        TableViewColumn{
            id:student_first_Name_id
            title: "FirstName"
            role: "FirstName"
            width: 100

        }
        TableViewColumn{
            id:student_last_Name_id
            title: "LastName"
            role: "LastName"
            width: 100

        }
        TableViewColumn{
            id:student_gender_id
            title: "Gender"
            role: "Gender"
            width: 300
            delegate: gender_delegate
        }
        Component{
            id:gender_delegate
            Item {
                visible: model.Gender.isStudent_QProperty? false : true
               // visible: styleData.value.isStudent_QProperty? true : false
                Row{
                    spacing: 10
                    RadioButton{
                        id:male_button
                        text: "Male"
                        checked: styleData.value === "male"? true : false
                    }
                    RadioButton{
                        text: "Female"
                        checked: male_button.checked? false : true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        TableViewColumn{
            id:student_age_id
            title: "Age"
            role: "Age"
            width: 100

        }
        TableViewColumn{
            id:student_ph_num_id
            title: "PhoneNumber"
            role: "PhoneNumber"
            width: 100

        }
    }
}
```

JSON file is, keep it in the working directory of the project
sample4.json

```
    {
"SchoolList": [
    {
    "SchoolName": "Faps",
    "Students": [
        {
            "Firstname": "abc",
            "LastName": "ask",
            "Age": 25,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "32423423"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "def",
            "LastName": "ask",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "1278371267"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "ijk",
            "LastName": "lmn",
            "Age": 25,
            "Gender": "Female",
            "PhoneNumber": "8372873187"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "opq",
            "LastName": "rst",
            "Age": 25,
            "Gender": "Female",
            "PhoneNumber": "2434234234"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "uvw",
            "LastName": "xyz",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "124331423"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "abcd",
            "LastName": "efgh",
            "Age": 12,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "1231323424"
        }
    ]
    },
{
    "SchoolName": "Germains",
    "Students": [
        {
            "Firstname": "lmno",
            "LastName": "pqr",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "234234"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "stuv",
            "LastName": "wxyz",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "123213"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "sfadf",
            "LastName": "dfsdf",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "Female",
            "PhoneNumber": "12323423"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "dsfsd",
            "LastName": "sdfsd",
            "Age": 30,
            "Gender": "Female",
            "PhoneNumber": "1231323"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "sdfsd",
            "LastName": "sdfsd",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "124331423"
        },
        {
            "Firstname": "awdas",
            "LastName": "cvfs",
            "Age": 26,
            "Gender": "male",
            "PhoneNumber": "1231323424"
        }
    ]
}   
]
}
```

When the code is run as given on pycharm we will see an output like this

[image]

There is male female radio buttons which is being applied to the parent elements, How can i do i make sure i remove those radio buttons for the parent and apply them only to children elements.

Comment: i have given the code of what exactly i have tried if you just run the code on pycharm you will be able to see the output result, can you tell me what i should do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure is confusing so I am going to implement the model from scratch to make it readable. On the other hand, instead of changing the visibility of the item, it is better to use a Loader so we only build the items if they are necessary.

Note: I have changed the json a bit so that the keys match the roles:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import IntEnum, auto
import json
import os
from pathlib import Path

from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

from PySide2.QtCore import (
    QAbstractItemModel,
    QByteArray,
    QCoreApplication,
    QModelIndex,
    Qt,
    QUrl,
)
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Student:
    FirstName: str
    LastName: str
    Age: int
    Gender: str
    PhoneNumber: str


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class School:
    SchoolName: str
    Students: list[Student] = field(default_factory=list)


class SchoolRoles(IntEnum):
    SchoolNameRole = Qt.UserRole


class StudentRoles(IntEnum):
    FirstnameRole = SchoolRoles.SchoolNameRole + 1
    LastNameRole = auto()
    AgeRole = auto()
    GenderRole = auto()
    PhoneNumberRole = auto()


ROLES_MAPPPING = {
    SchoolRoles.SchoolNameRole: "SchoolName",
    StudentRoles.FirstnameRole: "FirstName",
    StudentRoles.LastNameRole: "LastName",
    StudentRoles.AgeRole: "Age",
    StudentRoles.AgeRole: "Age",
    StudentRoles.GenderRole: "Gender",
    StudentRoles.PhoneNumberRole: "PhoneNumber",
}


@dataclass
class Model(QAbstractItemModel):
    schools: list[School] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._rolenames = dict()
        self._rolenames[Qt.DisplayRole] = QByteArray(b"display")
        for role, name in ROLES_MAPPPING.items():
            self._rolenames[role] = QByteArray(name.encode())

    def add_school(self, school):
        self.schools.append(school)

    def columnCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def roleNames(self):
        return self._rolenames

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            item = parent.internalPointer()
            if isinstance(item, School):
                return len(item.Students)
            return 0
        else:
            return len(self.schools)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if column != 0:
            return QModelIndex()
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QModelIndex()
        if parent.isValid():
            item = parent.internalPointer()
            if isinstance(item, School):
                return self.createIndex(row, column, item.Students[row])
            return QModelIndex()
        else:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, self.schools[row])

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if isinstance(item, School):
            return QModelIndex()
        elif isinstance(item, Student):
            row = -1
            parent_item = None
            for i, school in enumerate(self.schools):
                if item in school.Students:
                    row = i
                    parent_item = school
                    break
            if row >= 0:
                return self.createIndex(row, 0, parent_item)
        return QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(index.internalPointer())
        elif role == SchoolRoles.SchoolNameRole:
            if isinstance(item, School):
                return item.SchoolName
            elif isinstance(item, Student):
                return index.parent().internalPointer().SchoolName
            return
        elif isinstance(item, Student):
            prop = ROLES_MAPPPING.get(role)
            if prop is not None:
                return getattr(item, prop)


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication()

    model = Model()

    with open(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "sample.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for dict_school in data.get("SchoolList", []):
            school = School.from_dict(dict_school)
            model.add_school(school)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("schoolModel", model)
    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TreeView {
        id: schoolTreeView

        model: schoolModel
        anchors.fill: parent
        alternatingRowColors: true

        TableViewColumn {
            id: schoolName_id

            title: "SchoolName"
            role: "SchoolName"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            id: student_first_Name_id

            title: "FirstName"
            role: "FirstName"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            id: student_last_Name_id

            title: "LastName"
            role: "LastName"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Gender"
            role: "Gender"
            width: 150

            delegate: Loader {
                id: loader

                property string gender: styleData.value ? styleData.value : ""

                sourceComponent: styleData.value ? customDelegate : null
            }

        }

        TableViewColumn {
            id: student_age_id

            title: "Age"
            role: "Age"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            id: student_ph_num_id

            title: "PhoneNumber"
            role: "PhoneNumber"
            width: 100
        }

    }

    property Component customDelegate: Row {
        spacing: 10

        RadioButton {
            id: male_button

            text: "Male"
            checked: gender === "male"
        }

        RadioButton {
            text: "Female"
            checked: gender === "Female"
        }

    }

}
```

```json
{
    "SchoolList": [
        {
            "SchoolName": "Faps",
            "Students": [
                {
                    "FirstName": "abc",
                    "LastName": "ask",
                    "Age": 25,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "32423423"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "def",
                    "LastName": "ask",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "1278371267"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "ijk",
                    "LastName": "lmn",
                    "Age": 25,
                    "Gender": "Female",
                    "PhoneNumber": "8372873187"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "opq",
                    "LastName": "rst",
                    "Age": 25,
                    "Gender": "Female",
                    "PhoneNumber": "2434234234"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "uvw",
                    "LastName": "xyz",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "124331423"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "abcd",
                    "LastName": "efgh",
                    "Age": 12,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "1231323424"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SchoolName": "Germains",
            "Students": [
                {
                    "FirstName": "lmno",
                    "LastName": "pqr",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "234234"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "stuv",
                    "LastName": "wxyz",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "123213"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "sfadf",
                    "LastName": "dfsdf",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "Female",
                    "PhoneNumber": "12323423"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "dsfsd",
                    "LastName": "sdfsd",
                    "Age": 30,
                    "Gender": "Female",
                    "PhoneNumber": "1231323"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "sdfsd",
                    "LastName": "sdfsd",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "124331423"
                },
                {
                    "FirstName": "awdas",
                    "LastName": "cvfs",
                    "Age": 26,
                    "Gender": "male",
                    "PhoneNumber": "1231323424"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! your answer solves my question! Also thank you for making my data class simple.